# Recursion behaving in an unexpected manner with Java

Tags: java, string, recursion

I'm a student, and I've been working on the following challenge: find a substring (the needle) in a larger string (the haystack) without using the `substring` method, and using recursion. Recursion isn't my strong suit, but I have worked out the following:

```
public class Contains
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(contains("Java programming", "ogr", false));
    }

    public static boolean contains(String haystack, String needle, boolean doesContain)
    {
        if(haystack.length() < needle.length())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < needle.length(); i++)
            {
                if(haystack.charAt(i) != needle.charAt(i))
                    if((i + 1) == needle.length())
                        {
                            doesContain = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    else
                        break;
                else
                    if((i + 1) == needle.length())
                    {
                        doesContain = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
            }
            char[] haystackChar = haystack.toCharArray();
            char[] newCharArray = new char[(haystackChar.length - 1)];

            for(int j = 1; j < haystackChar.length; j++)
            {
                newCharArray[j - 1] = haystackChar[j];
            }

            String newStr = new String(newCharArray);

            if(doesContain == false)
                contains(newStr, needle, doesContain);
        }
        return doesContain;
    }
}
```

I realize this might not be the best or most elegant solution, but I am mostly just trying to get it to work. I've been running it in the Eclipse debugger, and everything is functioning as expected up until the call to `if(doesContain == false)` during the method call to `contain` where `doesContain` is set to true during the iteration of the for loop. The debugger is showing the value of `doesContain` to (correctly) be true, and it shows it skipping over the if statement, and exiting the else block. However, immediately after that, it jumps back up into the else block and only calls the recursive call to `contain`, instead of returning `doesContain`. Then, it continues to work recursively and subsequently fail and return false, because it's now searching through the rest of the string, where the "needle" is not located.

I know that StackOverflow is not a 'homework help' location per se, but I program for purposes other than school, and I'm quite perplexed as to why it's behaving this way. Does anyone know why it's doing this? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Oh man, I wish I were a girl to get spammed with answers! Anyway your (admittedly poorly formatted) code is working just fine. The problem is that you're discarding results of recursive calls. Change `contains(newStr, needle, doesContain);` to `return contains(newStr, needle, doesContain);` and vòila!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look through your code and ran it in eclipse myself. A theory you will want to look into is how stacking works in recursion. Your program is finding true and then leaving the stack, but by that point it had reoccurred several times. It returned true, but then also went on to return all the false variables that were stored before it.

If you have any further questions please let me know.

**EDIT** 
If you are really interested in getting into advanced recursion I highly recommend this video: [Java Recursion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neuDuf_i8Sg)

Hey, I didn't need to go that far to make it work. You can remove doesContain as a parameter and set it as a static instance variable and it worked for me.

```
public class Contains
{

    private static boolean doesContain = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(contains("Java programming", "ogr"));
    }

    public static boolean contains(String haystack, String needle)
    {
        if(haystack.length() < needle.length())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < needle.length(); i++)
            {
                if(haystack.charAt(i) != needle.charAt(i))
                    if((i + 1) == needle.length())
                        {
                            doesContain = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    else
                        break;
                else
                    if((i + 1) == needle.length())
                    {
                        doesContain = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
            }
            char[] haystackChar = haystack.toCharArray();
            char[] newCharArray = new char[(haystackChar.length - 1)];

            for(int j = 1; j < haystackChar.length; j++)
            {
                newCharArray[j - 1] = haystackChar[j];
            }

            String newStr = new String(newCharArray);

            if(doesContain == false)
                contains(newStr, needle);
        }
        return doesContain;
   }
}
```

What you had was very close, but by passing it as a parameter you were storing every time you went through another recursion. This way you only return your final value.

Comment: When you say set the variable to null, what variable do you mean? Something that already exists in my current code, or adding a new variable for the purpose of evaluating this? I somewhat understand what you're saying about the stack, and I didn't think about that before.

Comment: Hey @AbigailFox, sorry for the confusion. What I was talking about was a little more advanced than you need to go. By setting an instance variable you can keep one copy of doesContain and not store one for every step of recursion. This way you only return your final value.

Comment: Thank you! It works! And also thank you for your explanation, recursive thinking is probably the programming skill I am worst at. I hadn't even really thought about how my method was interacting with the stack and how the boolean was being handled with the repeated method calls.

Comment: Not a problem! I only recently learned advanced recursion, the methodology behind how stacks operate can be a little mind boggling at first. For future endeavors I recommend writing down what is returned with each stack like a staircase, and then going the opposite way to see what is done with it.

Answer (score 0):

To find a `needle` in the `haystack` in the way you want, you don't need to use recursion.

Just remove the following lines of code from your function and it will work just fine:

```
        char[] haystackChar = haystack.toCharArray();
        char[] newCharArray = new char[(haystackChar.length - 1)];

        for(int j = 1; j < haystackChar.length; j++)
        {
            newCharArray[j - 1] = haystackChar[j];
        }

        String newStr = new String(newCharArray);

        if(doesContain == false)
            contains(newStr, needle, doesContain);
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, using recursion is a requirement for the assignment. Personally, I find recursion much more difficult to understand, but I also realize that I have to practice it to be able to use it better. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sort of confusing yourself with the recursive function. One of the variables passed to the recursive function is `doesContain`, but the function is supposed to *return* whether the string contains it! In the lines

```
        if(doesContain == false)
            contains(newStr, needle, doesContain);
```

The call to `contains` will return if the substring contains the needle. You need to take that value, and return it back up the call stack.

Hopefully that made some sense. If that didn't, I'll give you the code so you can figure it out yourself:

```
public static boolean contains(String haystack, String needle)
{
    if(haystack.length() < needle.length())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        boolean doesContain=false;
        for(int i = 0; i < needle.length(); i++)
        {
            if(haystack.charAt(i) != needle.charAt(i))
                if((i + 1) == needle.length())
                    {
                        doesContain = false;
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    break;
            else
                if((i + 1) == needle.length())
                {
                    doesContain = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    continue;
        }
        char[] haystackChar = haystack.toCharArray();
        char[] newCharArray = new char[(haystackChar.length - 1)];

        for(int j = 1; j < haystackChar.length; j++)
        {
            newCharArray[j - 1] = haystackChar[j];
        }

        String newStr = new String(newCharArray);

        if(doesContain == false)
            return contains(newStr, needle);
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did actually have it like that before, adding the boolean into the method call was one of the fixes I tried to resolve my problem. I thought the issue might have been the fact that I was setting `doesContain` to false at the beginning of the method. It didn't really explain why it was jumping backwards, nor did it fix it, however, even without it the method still doesn't return the correct value.

Comment: @AbigailFox wait, I tested it, and it works. It's not jumping back, its jumping out of the function, back to the function that called it

Comment: What do you mean by that? How is it doing that?

Comment: @AbigailFox I mean its returning to the function that called it

Comment: Ah I got it now. I wasn't really thinking about the stack and how my function interacts with it, but I fixed it by making `doesContain` an instance variable that each method call accesses.